# Test passing in all environments except one

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have this test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MLoggerTest {

  @Mock private Appender<ILoggingEvent> mockAppender;
  @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> captorLoggingEvent;

  @InjectMocks private MLogger mLogger;

  private static final String TEST_MESSAGE = "test message";

  /** Initialisation */
  @Before
  public void setup() {
    Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    root.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    root.addAppender(mockAppender);
  }

  /** Cleanup after tests completed */
  @After
  public void teardown() {
    Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    root.detachAppender(mockAppender);
  }

  @Test
  public void info() {
    mLogger.info(TEST_MESSAGE, null);
    verify(mockAppender, times(1)).doAppend(captorLoggingEvent.capture());
    final LoggingEvent event = captorLoggingEvent.getValue();
    assertThat("Message not logged", event.getFormattedMessage(), containsString(TEST_MESSAGE));
  }

  @Test
  public void error() {
    mLogger.error(TEST_MESSAGE, null);
    verify(mockAppender, times(1)).doAppend(captorLoggingEvent.capture());
    final LoggingEvent event = captorLoggingEvent.getValue();
    assertThat("Message not logged", event.getFormattedMessage(), containsString(TEST_MESSAGE));
  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

> [ERROR] Failures:
> [ERROR]   MetricLoggerTest.info:52
> Wanted but not invoked:
> mockAppender.doAppend();
> -> at my.app.logging.MLoggerTest.info(MLoggerTest.java:52)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

`info()` passes on my local machine and in my dev environment but not in uat and `error()` passes in all environments even though it is pretty much the same test. I can't figure out why this would be. Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**
This only happens when the below test class is executed first:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LogExceptionBySalesRefAspectTest {

  private static final String SALES_REF = "ABC123-87";
  private static final String EXCEPTION_MSG = "Exception";
  private static final String MESSAGE =
      "Exception" + EXCEPTION_MSG + "encountered for sales reference " + SALES_REF;

  private MyAppender myAppender;
  private static final String LOGGER_NAME = "my.app.logging";

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);
    myAppender = new MyAppender();
    myAppender.setContext((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory());
    logger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    logger.addAppender(myAppender);
    myAppender.start();
  }

  @After
  public void cleanUp() {
    myAppender.reset();
    myAppender.stop();
  }

  @Test
  public void confirm_output_logged() {
    LogExceptionBySalesRefAspect aspect = new LogExceptionBySalesRefAspect();
    SalesRequest req = SalesRequest.builder().salesReference(QUOTE_REF).build();
    JoinPoint jp = Mockito.mock(JoinPoint.class);
    Mockito.when(jp.getArgs()).thenReturn(new Object[] {req});
    aspect.logExceptionWithSalesIdentification(jp, new ServiceException(EXCEPTION_MSG));
    assertThat(myAppender.countEventsForLogger(LOGGER_NAME)).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(myAppender.contains(MESSAGE, Level.ERROR));
  }

  @Test
  public void whenexception_on_postsales_call() {
    LogExceptionBySalesRefAspect aspect = new LogExceptionBySalesRefAspect();
    SalesRequest req = SalesRequest.builder().salesReference(QUOTE_REF).build();
    JoinPoint jp = Mockito.mock(JoinPoint.class);
    Mockito.when(jp.getArgs()).thenReturn(new Object[] {req});
    aspect.handlePostSalesExceptionLogging(jp, new ServiceException(EXCEPTION_MSG));
    assertThat(myAppender.countEventsForLogger(LOGGER_NAME)).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(myAppender.contains(MESSAGE, Level.ERROR));
  }
}
```

Comment: So it does fail locally if you run `LogExceptionBySalesRefAspectTest` first?

Comment: Yes. Apologies. Should have been clear about that.

Comment: Run it under the debugger, put a breakpoint in `info` and see what the state of the appenders are.

Comment: You are changing the appenders and the log level in your other test (that runs first). Logger configuration is global and you need to restore it if you change it in a test